# How to implement PayPal Virtual Terminal in salesforce Apex?

Tags: salesforce, paypal-sandbox, paypal-rest-sdk

I want to integrate PayPal with Salesforce so how can we integrate PayPal Virtual Terminal with salesforce that's my question?

If Anyone knows please answer the question.

I have PayPal sandbox account using this account I have made API Call like get token, create order etc.
but I also want to request API call of Virtual terminal which is not available because this is an App which needs to install in PayPal account there is no API of Virtual Terminal so I am stuck to proceed further.

Answer (score 0):

There is no API for Virtual Terminal itself, it's a [www.paypal.com](http://www.paypal.com) APP you would need to redirect over to (and login to PayPal to use).

In general [Advanced Credit and Debit Card Hosted Fields](https://developer.paypal.com/braintree/docs/start/hosted-fields) are recommended for processing cards in a custom way as the card number/cvv/expiration is collected by a small iframe for each field and nodes not travel through your server. But it also possible to use [the v2/checkout/orders create API call](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/orders/v2/#orders_create) with a `payment_source.card` object. For handling card numbers directly without an iframe, your system will need to be PCI SAQ-D compliant.